# Работа с файлом Intel Hex в Android приложении

Tags: android

Добрый день. Есть файл прошивки для микроконтроллеров Intel hex, который я храню в ресурсах android приложения. Требуется отправить содержимое этого файла на микроконтроллер.

Может кто сталкивался с прошивкой микроконтроллеров через Android приложение. Меня интересует сама работа с данным файлом. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно с ним работать или посоветуйте, что почитать на данную тему.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что контроллеры бывают сильно разные и методы работы с ними тоже...

Comment: Я же уточнил, что интересует работа именно на стороне андроида, а именно: работа с файлом intel hex. Может есть какие-то гайды на эту тему, я искал, но ничего не нашел

Comment: Формат там не сложный: читайте файл, преобразуете данные в нужный формат, посылаете на контроллер.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов данный процесс меня и интересуют. Судя по всему, я не правильно сформулировал вопрос. Пожалуй, я пересоздам с правильной формулировкой

Comment: Ну тащемта да: непонятно на какой стадии проблемы и в чем именно они выражаются :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов переформулировал свой вопрос - 
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634134/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5