# Чтение файла с бинарными данными в текстовом виде

Tags: java, android, io

Добрый день. У меня есть файл, который я храню в ресурсах приложения, а именно в raw. В данном файле размещены массив байт, как я понимаю, он в текстовом формате. Мне нужно считать его и преобразовать в массив байт.

Вот так выглядит файл:

> ...
>
> :200020000000000000000000000000001F020008210200080000000023020008714A00087C
>   :2000400027020008290200082B0200082D0200082F020008310200083302000835020008E0
>   :2000600037020008390200083B0200083D0200083F02000841020008430200084502000840
>
> ...

Я открываю файл и записываю его содержимое в массив `my_array`, однако при выведении содержимого массива в логи, конечно же отображается далеко не желаемый результат. Что-то мне подсказывает, что проблемы где-то на этом этапе :)
Как я понимаю, перед записыванием элемента из файла в массив байт, его нужно преобразовывать (так ли это???). Вообщем, подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так и как сделать правильно.

```
String filename = "file_name";
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "raw", getPackageName());
    byte[] my_array;

try {
       my_array  = getText(id, context);

     } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Метод getText:

```
public byte[] getText(int id, Context context) throws IOException {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(id);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];

        try {
            int read;
            do {
                read = is.read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.length);
                if(read == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                bout.write(readBuffer, 0, read);
            } while(true);

            return bout.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: На всякий случай спрошу - не делал ли кто такое на C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код интепретирует текст как символы (char) и записывает их бинарное представление в ByteArrayOutputStream.
Если исходный файл содержит текст в HEX формате, то следует конвертировать этот hex в байты.

```
byte[] hexToBinary(String str){
    byte[] data = new byte[str.length()/2];
    for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        data[i] = (byte) ((Character.digit(str.charAt(2*i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(str.charAt(2*i+1), 16));
    }

    return data;
}
```

В эту функцию передать строку из байтов полученных из `is.read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.length);` и уже результат записать в ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
do {
     read = is.read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.length);
     if(read == -1) {
        break;
     }
     String hex = new String(readBuffer);
     byte[] data = hexToBinary(hex);
     bout.write(data);
   } while(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, но я совсем запутался. Я сильно плаваю в кодировке данных. Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь. У меня есть файл с расширением .hex. Там хранятся символы в виде char вот такого формата :
`:020000040800F2
:20000000103C0020650200081502000817020008190200081B0200081D0200080000000056`
Я должен считать их в потоке InputStream, они будут в виде массива байт, потом я должен преобразовать их в String, далее в String`е искать совпадения уже с бинарным формат и преобразовывать?

Comment: @Denis422 Попробуем разобраться. Вы имеете дело с форматом Intel HEX https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX В этом формате каждая запись начинается с символа ":". Если задача заключается лишь в том, чтобы просто записать все байты подряд в ByteArrayOutputStream, то нужно еще удалять символ ":" из строки (hex.replace(":", "") затем эту строку передать в функцию hexToBinary() которая вернет массив байтов для записи в BAOStream. 
1) Считать часть InputStream в readBuffer
2) преобразовать readBuffer в String, удалить ":"
3) Записать байты из строки в bout
4) Следующая итерация